# insert data into vertica from MATLAB

Tags: database, matlab, insert, vertica

I have to insert millions of data from MATLAB into Vertica. I tried using the *datainsert* function given in MATLAB but it seems slow as it takes about 6 seconds for 3000 records. The other functions *fastinsert* and *insert* are even slower. Is there a faster method to insert the data?

Comment: Is there any method for Vertica which is known to be faster (other programming language / import from file or whatever)?

Comment: Vertica native COPY is one method as mentioned by @Up_One but I'm not sure if I can insert only selected columns in the table which is what my work needs me to do. Only a selected columns are to be inserted and others to be kept Null for later purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and export the data into csv format. See this [link](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) for more details.
 Vertica performance on sequential insert statements is poor. You have to use Vertica native COPY command to load data from the exported csv file, will do about 1 million rows per  sec in a small single node Cluster.

Comment: My data is in cell array which cannot be written using csvwrite function given in the link

Comment: Cell array has datetime timestamp which is a string for all the records

Comment: Also I need to insert data into only a few columns in the table not all.

Comment: So i guess you cannot pass the data into a text file ? - and you can use copy command to insert only in few columns and not all, by using the filler option.